# How can we use the termux?

Tags: android, external, termux

**how** can we use the termux into the sd card and run the kali linux using the nethunter into the extern

> Blockquote
> installing termux

al *storage* into the phone !

Answer (score 1):

I could not get your question but i believe this is the link you are looking for

[Official Termux installation guide Github](https://github.com/termux/termux-app#installation).

However, there is an issue with termux in Android 11.
Please follow the above link. If it does not work raise an issue with your device information in the same link